# How can I change text color of my InputText in ImGui?

Tags: c++, button, imgui

I am looking to figure out how I can change the color of the text displayed on the "Name" print, but I am pretty much clueless on how to do so. I would like to make it green, help or tips are appreciated :D

```
// Name
            ImGui::InputText("Name", selected_entry.name, 32);
```

Comment: q.v. https://github.com/ocornut/imgui/issues/2144

Comment: I changed the title because of the 2 current answers have nothing at all to do with ImGui which is the topic of the question.

Answer (score 17):

Globally the text color can be changed using style

```cpp
ImGuiStyle* style = &ImGui::GetStyle();
style->Colors[ImGuiCol_Text] = ImVec4(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.00f);
```

Color of a single widget alone can be changed by push/pop styles

```cpp
char txt_green[] = "text green";
char txt_def[] = "text default";

// Particular widget styling
ImGui::PushStyleColor(ImGuiCol_Text, IM_COL32(0,255,0,255));
ImGui::InputText("##text1", txt_green, sizeof(txt_green));
ImGui::PopStyleColor();

...

// Use global style colors
ImGui::InputText("##text2", txt_def, sizeof(txt_def));
```

Output:

[image: color text inputs]

Again if you want separate colors for input text and label i would suggest to go with two widgets easily.

```cpp
char txt_def[] = "text default";

ImGui::InputText("##Name", txt_def, sizeof(txt_def));
ImGui::SameLine();
ImGui::PushStyleColor(ImGuiCol_Text, IM_COL32(0, 255, 0, 255));
ImGui::Text("Name");
ImGui::PopStyleColor();
```

[image: Output:]